# Is it possible to run OpenMPI compiled executable on machine without OpenMPI?

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmpi

I compile OpenMPI code for Fortran using *mpif90* and run the executable using *mpirun*. My university grants me access to a large number of clusters, which however do not have OpenMPI libraries installed (and therefore do not recognize the two commands above). Is it possible to compile the source code on a local machine and generate a "readable" executable for such clusters?

Comment: No. The executables are not portable. Moreover, you need MPI runtime to run your code. Note that you can always compile/install the Open MPI under your user account.

Comment: Note that OpenMPI is only one of many MPI implementations. Contact your cluster administrators to find out how to load MPI on those clusters. There should be something installed but maybe not visible.

Comment: Well, if you could generate static binaries and probably rely on tcp/ip communications then it would be a good start because of reducing the library dependencies. However, the most difficult thing would be to have the appropriate mpi launcher (mpirun).

Comment: [mpi-forum](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.1/mpi21-report-bw/node193.htm) suggests a standardized startup mechanism  `mpiexec -n <numprocs> <program>` that should improve portability. I am not sure if it is working in general, never tested.

Comment: @Harald I think that's the whole point of the MPI library :-) . Suppose you have the launcher, how are you gonna do the collective operations?! And remember that we are talking about HPC. So, performance matters. Yes, you can always reinvent the wheel but I think compiling and installing an MPI library which take probably 10-15 minutes is way faster.

Comment: @Arash, sorry not to share your view. Static libraries is an already existing functionality so we don't reinvent anything, simply avoid the user to install everything. You can still do collective operations and possibly use some vendor comm libraries. I agree that installing the libraries is an extremely easy task but that was OP question. Note also that OP has not referred to or labelled HPC, so maybe he only wants to do some testing.

Comment: @Harald -- That made me search around and I guess you are right. [Can I build 100% static MPI applications?](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=mpi-apps#static-mpi-apps). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Arash. Good finding. I think that this could be considered as an answer to OP.

Comment: Thank you, guys!!! The link @Arash provided is very helpful!